# Install Chromium OS, but not from a USB

Tags: multi-boot, operating-systems, chromium

How can I install Chromium OS on my PC? I do not mean in a virtual machine, but actually a dual boot.

I know you can [boot from a USB](https://superuser.com/questions/89483/usb-bootable-of-chromium-os), but that is not what I'm looking for.

I really want to install Chromium OS right on my PC. I would like to have it dual boot with Windows 7 (32bit).

Comment: Have a look at [USB bootable of Chromium OS](http://superuser.com/questions/89483/usb-bootable-of-chromium-os)

Comment: Ummm i want to have it literally installed on my pc as i make clear in my question, also have a dual boot. No USB.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/79182/install-chromium-os-to-second-internal-drive-on-eee-901 - If that question isn't the same, edit/comment the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Download Chrome OS VMWare image](http://gdgt.com/discuss/download-chrome-os-vmware-image-after-5hb/) :

> After Google announced the
>   availability of the Chrome OS /
>   Chromium OS source code, one of our
>   engineers (Jon Ursenbach), immediately
>   got to work on compiling the code,
>   trying to see if he could get an
>   instance of Chromium OS running in a
>   virtual machine.
>
> He was finally able to do it! You can
>   download a copy of the virtual machine
>   to use in VMware, VirtualBox, and on a
>   USB drive [here](http://gdgt.com/google/chrome-os/download/) (300MB compressed
>   / 700MB uncompressed, registration
>   required)

**EDIT**

See this article:
[How To Install Chrome OS Into Hard disk Alongside Your Existing Operating System.](http://www.digitalability.co.cc/2010/01/how-to-install-chrome-os-in-to-hard.html)

Comment: that isn't helping - that's for vmware or usb - i want to use neither of those. I want it on a disk or a usb where i can actually install it on my computer.

Comment: @TutorialPoint: See my edit.

Comment: have anything changed in the last 2 years?

Comment: @Vam'çá: See [this site](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Cloudready can be installed locally, but its not Chromium OS "pure", I just got mine installed on a raw disk PC, I don't know exactly what is the difference to the actual Chromium OS. You just need to boot from USB then install from settings, reboot, done.

https://www.neverware.com/freedownload